# What is X in a syllable C=consonant, V=vowel

Tags: phonology, hebrew, syllables, phonetic-symbols

I don't under stand (X) and (s/sh) in this sentence.
As opposed to Hebrew CV(X)(C), the non-Semitic syllable structure of Israeli, (s/sh)(C)(C)V(C)(C)(s/sh)

Comment: Where did your sentence come from?

Comment: Ghil‘ad Zuckermann, "Hybridity versus Revivability: Multiple Causation, Forms and Patterns".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know already

- C means consonants
- V means vowels

And

- X means any phoneme
- s means /s/
- sh means /ʃ/
- () means the phoneme in brackets is optional